# PHP combining arsort & ksort

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array by value descending keeping keys (`arsort`), but if the values are equal I want it also sorted in order of keys ascending (`ksort`).

I've been trying this:

```
ksort($array);
arsort($array);
```

But the ksort is not kept, and the keys get jumbled up again after the `arsort`.

E.g. if my input array in:

```
$array[0] = 4;
$array[1] = 2;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[3] = 1;
$array[4] = 4;
```

I want to sort it so it ends like this:

```
$array[0] = 4;
$array[4] = 4;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[1] = 2;
$array[3] = 1;
```

NOT like this:

```
$array[4] = 4;
$array[0] = 4;
$array[2] = 3;
$array[1] = 2;
$array[3] = 1;
```

But the previous order of the keys appears to be disturbed by `arsort`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preserve key order (stable sort) when sorting with PHP's uasort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353739/preserve-key-order-stable-sort-when-sorting-with-phps-uasort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP dropped stable sorting (which guaranteed the ordering you wanted) in PHP 4.1:
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53341&edit=1

Here's a seemingly dupe question, with a code snippet, to work around it (basically: write your own sort function. Boo.):
[Preserve key order (stable sort) when sorting with PHP's uasort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353739/preserve-key-order-stable-sort-when-sorting-with-phps-uasort)

Answer (score 0):

That's a pity, since it's not supported, here's a function I wrote for it:

```
function arksort($array)
    {
    arsort($array);
    $newarray=array();
    $temp=array();
    $on=current($array);
    foreach($array as $key => $val)
        {
        if ($val===$on) $temp[$key]=$val;
        else
            {
            ksort($temp);
            $newarray=$newarray+$temp;
            $temp=array();
            $on=$val;
            $temp[$key]=$val;
            }
        }
    ksort($temp);
    $newarray=$newarray+$temp;
    reset($newarray);
    return $newarray;
    }
```