# PHP - How to move the empty values of an array to its last positions

Tags: php, arrays

How can I move the empty values of an array to its last position?

For example:

```
$givenArray = array( 
                    0=>'green', 
                    1=>'', 
                    2=>'red', 
                    3=>'', 
                    4=>'blue'
                  );

$requiredArray = array(
                       0=>'green',
                       1=>'red',
                       2=>'blue',
                       3=>'',
                       4=>'' 
                      );
```

Provided that the non empty values should not be sorted. It should be as it is, i.e. only the empty values should move to the end of an array.

I need exactly what my examples show.

Comment: I think you picked the wrong answer as answer... Hakre's answer is definitely best way to go and apparently that did work for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are much better/more elegant answers in this thread already, but this works too:

```
//strip empties and move to end
foreach ($givenArray as $key => $value)
{ 
    if ($value === "")
    { 
        unset($givenArray[$key]);
        $givenArray[] = $value;
    }
}

// rebuild array index
$givenArray = array_values($givenArray);
```

[Codepad demo](http://codepad.org/ivhUlboE)

Comment: I compacted the code-example. FYI: Foreach is iterating over an array copy, so you don't need to iterate twice for the operation.

Answer (score 8):

You are looking for all values not being an empty string (`""`) first and then all values being an empty string:

```
$requiredArray = array_diff($givenArray, array('')) 
                 + array_intersect($givenArray, array(''));
```

This will give you:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> string(5) "green"
  [2]=> string(3) "red"
  [4]=> string(4) "blue"
  [1]=> string(0) ""
  [3]=> string(0) ""
}
```

Which has the benefit that it preserves key => value association. If you need to renumber the keys, just apply the [`array_values`](http://php.net/array_values) function:

```
$requiredArray = array_values($requiredArray);
```

This will turn it into your required layout ([Demo](http://codepad.org/hEBLn2V2)):

```
array(5) {
  [0]=> string(5) "green"
  [1]=> string(3) "red"
  [2]=> string(4) "blue"
  [3]=> string(0) ""
  [4]=> string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer for simplicity, originality and best functionality. Of all answers, this is the best way to go.

Answer (score 6):

Try using [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
function empty_sort ($a, $b) {
    if ($a == '' && $b != '') return 1;
    if ($b == '' && $a != '') return -1;
    return 0; 
}

usort($array, 'empty_sort');
```

Which gives ([Demo](http://codepad.org/xflho6Y7)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => blue
    [1] => green
    [2] => red
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
)
```

Comment: you want to swap `-1` and `1`, I think. Also, this won't leave the non-empty elements in the same order.

Comment: Did not realise PHP does not do stable sorting. Here is a stable version of usort: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4353844/1220966

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
function sortempty( $a, $b ) {
    return empty( $a );
}

usort( $array, 'sortempty' );
```

Output ([Demo](http://codepad.org/Gerx4nfd)):

```
Array
(
    [0] => blue
    [1] => green
    [2] => red
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
)
```

[`usort()`](http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) allows you to sort an array using a user-defined function. I return if `$a` is empty or not. If it's empty, return 1 which makes value `$a` shift right (or down) in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm getting the result like this Array
Array
(
    [0] => blue
    [1] => green
    [2] => red
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
) here the values are getting sorted. but it should be like this (
    [0] => green
    [1] => red
    [2] => blue
    [3] => 
    [4] => 
)

Comment: @Raja I think that's a side-effect of using `usort()`. If you return 0 at all times, it still sorts alphabetically.

Answer (score 1):

```
$givenArray = array(
                    0=>'green',
                    1=>'',
                    2=>'red',
                    3=>'',
                    4=>'blue'
                  );

foreach($givenArray as $value){
    if(empty($value)){
        $newarray[] = $value;
    }else{
        $filledarray[] = $value;
    }
}
$requiredArray = array_merge($filledarray,$newarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is [usort($array, $callback)](http://php.net/usort) function that will sort with your own custom callback.