# How to reorder elements in an array when many values are empty?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list array

```
array([img1] => "", [img2] => "AJKH.png", [img3] => "", [img4] => "")
array([img1] => "", [img2] => "AJKH.png", [img3] => "IHGF.png", [img4] => "")
```

How to reorder when some value in array are empty. How ideas?

```
array([img1] => "AJKH.png", [img2] => "", [img3] => "", [img4] => "")
array([img1] => "AJKH.png", [img2] => "IHGF.png", [img3] => "", [img4] => "")
```

Comment: You can try sorting the array. Also if its fine, you can loop though the array and unset the empty spaces.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395395/php-how-to-move-the-empty-values-of-an-array-to-its-last-positions

Answer (score 1):

The proposed duplicate is almost the same, but this one seems a little different because it looks like you want to keep your keys in the same order (not maintain key-value association) and just move the values around based on whether or not they are empty. This should do that:

```
$new_array = array_fill_keys(array_keys($array), '');
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value) {
        $new_array[key($new_array)] = $value;
        next($new_array);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach is to have 2 arrays and merge them (it will be better, rather than swapping in terms of computation).

```
$empty=array();
$full=array();

foreach($yourArray  as $value){
if($value==""){
    $empty[]=$value;
}
else{
   $full[]=$value;
}
}

$result = array_merge($full, $empty);
```

Another approach is to write an algorithm that will check the position of the element (empty) and swap them. Bring all the empty on the end.