# How to have a stable sort in PHP with arsort()?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i need to sort an array in php **based on value**, array use some numbers for keys and values, for example like this:

```
$a = array(70 => 1 ,82 => 5  ,61 => 3 ,55 => 1 ,34 => 2 ,53 => 2 ,21 => 4 ,13 => 5);
```

**i like to sort it like this**:

```
Array
(
    [82] => 5
    [13] => 5
    [21] => 4
    [61] => 3
    [34] => 2
    [53] => 2
    [70] => 1
    [55] => 1
)
```

i used `arsort` and it worked, but there is a problem because this function make change defult sorted **keys** and sort array to:

```
Array
(
    [13] => 5
    [82] => 5
    [21] => 4
    [61] => 3
    [53] => 2
    [34] => 2
    [55] => 1
    [70] => 1
)
```

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: I 'm not so sure. Unless I 'm mistaken the OP wants a stable sort, not a multiple-criteria sort.

Comment: i read all of them, none exactly related to this problem!

Comment: This entire page is now obsolete. See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/stable_sorting#:~:text=A%20stable%20sort%20guarantees%20that,some%20part%20of%20that%20data.  Stable sorting has been implemented 3 years ago.

Comment: As of PHP 8, all built-in sort functions are stable. Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Construct a new array whose elements are the original array's keys, values, and also position:

```
$temp = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  $temp[] = array($i, $key, $value);
  $i++;
}
```

Then sort using a user-defined order that takes the original position into account:

```
uasort($temp, function($a, $b) {
 return $a[2] == $b[2] ? ($a[0] - $b[0]) : ($a[2] < $b[2] ? 1 : -1);
});
```

Finally, convert it back to the original associative array:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($temp as $val) {
  $array[$val[1]] = $val[2];
}
```

Comment: funny in almost 5 years no-one noticed that instead of `($a[0] > $b[0])` it should be `($a[0] > $b[0] ? 1 : -1)`, otherwise `false` is returned on reversed elements, which causes an undefined order. (Note also that `$a[0] == $b[0]` is impossible.)

Comment: @WalterTross Good catch. I changed it to `$a[0] - $b[0]`. I could also change the ternary at the end to `$b[2] - $a[2]`, but if it ain't broke ...

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `sort` family of functions are not [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). If you need the sort to be stable then you either have to implement it yourself, or iterate over the sorted result and "correct" the positions of the elements using [`array_splice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php).

Comment: +1 from me, just wanted to add the link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4353844/1229023) describing the process of creating a sorting function in more details. )

Comment: what about this way: arsort($a);
asort($a);
arsort($a); this worked!

Comment: @Vahid: It *happened* to work. There is no guarantee that it will work next time.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution with `array_multisort`.

```
$assoc = [
    70 => 1,
    82 => 5,
    61 => 3,
    55 => 1,
    34 => 2,
    53 => 2,
    21 => 4,
    13 => 5,
];

$keys = array_keys($assoc);
array_multisort($assoc, SORT_DESC, range(1, count($assoc)), $keys);
$assoc = array_combine($keys, $assoc);

print_r($assoc);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is kinda a big workaround, but it does work:

```
$a = array(70 => 1 ,82 => 5  ,61 => 3 ,55 => 1 ,34 => 2 ,53 => 2 ,21 => 4 ,13 => 5);
$b = max($a);
$c = min($a);
$d = 0;
$sorted_list = array();
while($b >= $c){
    foreach($a as $key => $value){
        if($value == $b){
            $sorted_list[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $b--;
}
```

vardump output:

```
array(8) { [82]=> string(1) "5" [13]=> string(1) "5" [21]=> string(1) "4" [61]=> string(1) "3" [34]=> string(1) "2" [53]=> string(1) "2" [70]=> string(1) "1" [55]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: good! but why i get Undefined offset for line             $sorted_list[$key] .= $value;?

Comment: I don't know why you get that and I didn't, but I do know how to fix it. Two lines added in my answer.

Comment: error disappeared, but array have wrong and empty values: Array
(
    [70] => 1
    [82] => 
    [61] => 
    [55] => 1
    [34] => 
    [53] => 
    [21] => 
    [13] => 
)

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own sorting funtion that meets your custom sorting criteria and then use usort() to iterate all over the array using the function you created to sort the array.

Comment: What sorting function could he use to get a stable sort? The original position in the array is not passed as a parameter to the comparison function.

Answer (score 0):

PHP use quicksort as base sorting-algorithms.
You hae two options:

1. first Uses usort and define a compare-function, which respect the former order
2. programm your own stable sorting-mechanism

I have programmed a package porth/avalanchesort (https://github.com/porthd/avalanchesort) on github, which contains a recursive naturell-merge-sort. You can use your own comparsionfunction and your own data-structure. The package contains an example for associative arrays and for list-arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with PHP 8, all built-in sort functions are stable.  See [PHP RFC: Make sorting stable](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/stable_sorting).

When working with PHP 7, I can recommend the [vanderlee/php-stable-sort-functions](https://packagist.org/packages/vanderlee/php-stable-sort-functions) package, which adds stable alternatives for all sorting functions.  They are also likely more performant than other code posted here and have unit tests.  As of version 2.0.6 it will also fallback to the native built-ins when running on PHP 8, making it ideal for library code that needs to work on PHP 7 and PHP 8.