# Is Eloquent sortBy stable in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

Is the sorting function on Laravel 5 Eloquent collections a stable sort? A stable sort will not reorder elements with equal sort key.

That is, given this input list:

```
| order | value |
|-------+-------|
| 5     | a     |
| 2     | b     |
| 5     | c     |
| 10    | d     |
```

Can I expect `$list->sortBy('order')` to always return the following result?

```
| order | value |
|-------+-------|
| 2     | b     |
| 5     | a     | <-- a and c have not
| 5     | c     | <-- switched places
| 10    | d     |
```

Comment: You could always test this and find the answer out for yourself.

Comment: @MartinBean you can't test if it is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source code can be found in [Illuminate/Support/Collection.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5e3bdacaf725e4709ed91ecf6fcb8d9ed3c8620e/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php):

```
public function sortBy($callback, $options = SORT_REGULAR, $descending = false)
{
    $results = [];
    if ( ! $this->useAsCallable($callback))
    {
        $callback = $this->valueRetriever($callback);
    }
    // First we will loop through the items and get the comparator from a callback
    // function which we were given. Then, we will sort the returned values and
    // and grab the corresponding values for the sorted keys from this array.
    foreach ($this->items as $key => $value)
    {
        $results[$key] = $callback($value, $key);
    }
    $descending ? arsort($results, $options)
                : asort($results, $options);
    // Once we have sorted all of the keys in the array, we will loop through them
    // and grab the corresponding model so we can set the underlying items list
    // to the sorted version. Then we'll just return the collection instance.
    foreach (array_keys($results) as $key)
    {
        $results[$key] = $this->items[$key];
    }
    $this->items = $results;
    return $this;
}
```

Since the [sort() family isn't stable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12676571/1544337), this function won't be stable either.

There are [stable PHP sort functions](https://github.com/vanderlee/PHP-stable-sort-functions), but if you want to use them you'll need to patch Laravel.

Comment: Hm, too bad. And there is no native sort option for a stable sort either.

Comment: @EmilVikström nope - I found stable PHP sort functions and added them, but you'd have to patch Laravel if you want to use them.