# Enhancing asort by order of keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am using `asort` to sort the numeric array. For e.g.

`$arr = [0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3];`

After running `asort` I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [4] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [6] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [7] => 3
)
```

But I am expecting to get it in this order:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
)
```

See the difference in order of the keys above.

Comment: Quoting from the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php): `If any of these sort functions evaluates two members as equal then the order is undefined (the sorting is not stable).` So you shouldn't expect key sequence to be maintained for elements with the same value, this is the documented behaviour

Comment: @MarkBaker I want to make it's order defined and sorting as stable. :)

Comment: Then you'll need to write your own sort function to do so: PHP doesn't have a function that will do it for you.... [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12676521/how-to-have-a-stable-sort-in-php-with-arsort) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First `sort` the `array`.
Then generate an `array` by flipping in a way so that the `key`s can be separated according to `value`s. Sort the arrays with keys and merge them to an array. And the combine the keys with the sorted values.

```
$arr = [0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3];

asort($arr);
$sorted = $arr;

$flipped = $new_keys = array();
foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
   $flipped[$val][] = $key; // Get the keys
}

foreach($flipped as $key => $val_array) {
    asort($val_array); // Sort the keys
    $new_keys = array_merge($new_keys, $val_array);
}

$final = array_combine($new_keys, $sorted); // Combine them again
var_dump($final);
```

**Output**

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  int(0)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
  [4]=>
  int(1)
  [3]=>
  int(2)
  [5]=>
  int(2)
  [6]=>
  int(2)
  [7]=>
  int(3)
}
```

Comment: This is not the output OP wants (for example a "1" value has index 4).

Comment: You have actually reordered them changing the keys also.

Comment: Humm... yup... but there are now 2 solutions on this question, one by you and another by @Rizier123 . Just curious to know which one should be less time consuming.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

First walk through each array value with [`array_walk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and change each value to an array containing the value and the key.

After this use [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to sort your array and if both values are the same you use the key to choose which one should be first.

At the end just use [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to transform your array back.

```
<?php

    $arr = [0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3];
    array_walk($arr, function(&$v, $k){
        $v = ["value" => $v, "key" => $k];
    });

    uasort($arr, function($a, $b){
        if($a["value"] == $b["value"]) {
            if($a["key"] == $b["key"])
                return 0;
            return $a["key"] > $b["key"] ? 1 : -1;
        }
        return $a["value"] > $b["value"] ? 1 : -1;
    });
    $arr = array_column($arr, "value", "key");

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 3
)
```

Comment: Humm... yup... but there are now 2 solutions on this question now, one by you and another by @b0s3 . Just curious to know which one should be less time consuming.

Comment: @codelearner Look at it for yourself: http://3v4l.org/aSPXJ/perf#tabs ; http://3v4l.org/3Ifc7/perf#tabs and http://3v4l.org/DdXGf/perf#tabs

Comment: @codelearner Also just to note this, if you look at the results above, make sure to look only at PHP 5.5+ for my answer, since under that version mine does not work.

Comment: I have voted your solution but based on the time consumption I have to accept @b0s3 solution. Thanks for your time though.