# AutoIncrement (re-order) php Array values

Tags: php

is there any way to reorder values in array? for example i have

```
 Array (
    "one" => 0,
     "tow" => 0,
     "three" => 0,
     "four" => 8,
     "apple" => 4,
     "pink" => 3,
   );
```

and convert it to

```
 Array (
    "one" => 0,
     "tow" => 1,
     "three" => 2,
     "pink" => 3,
     "apple" => 4,
     "four" => 5,
   );
```

### EDIT:

please notice that "four" has bigger value it should change to 5 and "apple" &  "pink" should not change

Answer (score 6):

How about as simple as...

```
$source  = array('one' => 0, 'tow' => 0, 'three' => 0, 'four' => 8, 'apple' => 4, 'pink' => 3);
asort($source);
$result  = array_flip(array_keys($source));
```

Explanation: `array_keys` will collect all the keys of your original array as another, *indexed* array, and `array_flip` will just turn these indexes into values. )

Comment: Will the array_keys not just be "one", "tow", "three" since array_keys also returns strings?

Comment: @Jonasm The result of array_keys will look like `array(0 => 'one', 1 => 'tow', 2 => 'three')`. array_flip will, well, flip this array, so it becomes `('one' => 0, 'tow' => 1, 'three' => 2)`: keys turn to values, values turn to keys. )

Comment: @raina77ow Yeah my bad. :-) gg

Comment: He wanted it sorted before the flip, note that `four` is in another position in the second array. Add that and I think that this answer is a winner :)

Comment: @PederN )) Added this to the answer, then saw your comment. ) Anyway, good catch. )

Comment: please notice that "four" has bigger value, it should be 5 not the 'pink'

Comment: @h0mayun No, it works exactly like that. There's another pitfall here with no easy workarounds: PHP sorting functions do not provide stable sorting: when two elements of the original array have the same value, their ordering in the resulting array is undefined. Check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353739/preserve-key-order-stable-sort-when-sorting-with-phps-uasort) for the replacement function, if that's an issue in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = 0;
foreach( $array as $key => $value )
{
    $array[$key] = $i;
    $i++
}
```

Should do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [PHP asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php).

Comment: He wants to renumber, not to sort.