# usort changing the order of array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array, usort

I have an array like this in my scenario

```
$arr[0]['id']=1200;
$arr[0]['rate']=7.0;
$arr[1]['id']=1380;
$arr[1]['rate']=7.0;
$arr[2]['id']=1568;
$arr[2]['rate']=7.0;
$arr[3]['id']=1933;
$arr[3]['rate']=7.0;
```

when I sorted it using the usort as below, it reversed the order

```
usort($arr,function($a, $b) {
        return $b['rate'] < $a['rate'];
});


[1933,1568,1380,1200]
```

but I want it to remain in the same order as it is inputted, if the `rate` is same, as represented below

```
[1200,1380,1568,1933]
```

Please help,
thanks in advance

Comment: Apologies - I was about to delete my post when you commented. Unfortunately the behaviour of usort changed way back in 4.1, such that what you're asking for isn't possible using that function. There are a lot of solutions for what you're asking in the [comments in the manual](http://php.net/usort). Search for "equal" and you'll find them

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353739/preserve-key-order-stable-sort-when-sorting-with-phps-uasort for a ready to use solution