# PHP - Sort arrays by keys and values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Hello how to sort arrays by keys and values too... so if user input this value

```
$input = array(0,1,0,2,0);
```

then the result should be like this since they're the same input they should maintain their keys too...

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [4] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 2
)
```

not like this... the keys is jumbled and I really that key to work on my project of FCFS Scheduling.

```
Array
(
    [4] => 0
    [0] => 0
    [2] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 2
)
```

btw I used asort. someone help me how to fix this?

Comment: this link may help you
http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: all basic ways to sort arrays and data in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/reference-all-basic-ways-to-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: wait.. subscript 0 is always first key.

Comment: @VandanaPareek none of that work...

Comment: @JeffLouie: Can you explain how you got the first output? I can't see how your keys are ordered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353739/preserve-key-order-stable-sort-when-sorting-with-phps-uasort

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

$a = array(0,1,0,2,0);

usort($a, "cmp");

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    echo " $value\n";
}
```

Comment: or you could use sort($input); also

Answer (score 0):

Stable sort would help here. But php don't have any stable sorting functions since 4.1.
But you can use uksort + closure.

```
$input = array(0,1,0,2,0);

$cmp = function($a, $b) use($input){
    if($input[$a] > $input[$b]){return 1;}
    elseif($input[$a] < $input[$b]){return -1;}
    elseif($a>$b){return 1;}
    elseif($a<$b){return -1;}
    return 0;
};

uksort($input, $cmp);

print_r($input);
```

https://eval.in/145923

Or shorter version

```
$cmp = function($a, $b) use($input){
    return (($input[$a]-$input[$b])?:($a-$b));
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**Simple use the `sort function`**

```
$input = array(0,1,0,2,0);

sort($input);

Result:-
    Array
    (
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 0
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 2
    )
```