# Sort rows of a 2d array by a column ascending, but with all false values at the end

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, custom-sort

I have a multidimensional array that I'd like to sort based on the distance value where the false values should be added to the end in their former positions regarding their arrays.

```
$array = array(
        array('name' => 'Array 1', 'distance' => 3.4),
        array('name' => 'Array 2', 'distance' => 2.4),
        array('name' => 'Array 3', 'distance' => false),
        array('name' => 'Array 4', 'distance' => 5.4),
        array('name' => 'Array 5', 'distance' => false),
        array('name' => 'Array 6', 'distance' => 1),
        array('name' => 'Array 7', 'distance' => false),
        array('name' => 'Array 8', 'distance' => false),
        array('name' => 'Array 9', 'distance' => 3.6),
    );
```

I'd like to sort it to this:

```
Array 6 1
Array 2 2.4
Array 1 3.4
Array 9 3.6
Array 4 5.4
Array 3 
Array 5 
Array 7 
Array 8
```

I can only get it to this:

```
Array 6 1
Array 2 2.4
Array 1 3.4
Array 9 3.6
Array 4 5.4
Array 8 
Array 5 
Array 3 
Array 7
```

My attempt:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    if(!$b['distance'])
        return -1;
    elseif(!$a['distance'])
        return 1;

    return $a['distance'] - $b['distance'];
});
```

**EDIT:** added my solution as an answer

Comment: note that a distance of `0` will be treated as a boolean, use `is_bool` instead, or `$b['distance'] === true || $b['distance'] === false` instead (`===` for type and value check)

Comment: If distances are equal or both are NULL, compare Name

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem distance will never be 0, but thanks for the observation

Comment: @splash58 this is just a dummy array. The real one doesn't contain a value like the Name here, so I can't do that :)

Comment: @ifsession then array_filter to select null element array, remove them from array, sort others and merge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$withDistance = array();
$withoutDistance = array_filter($array, function($array) use (&$withDistance) {
    if($array['distance'] !== false) {
        $withDistance[] = $array;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
});

usort($withDistance, function($a, $b){
    if ($a['distance'] == $b['distance']) return 1;
    return $a['distance'] > $b['distance'] ? 1: -1;
});

$array = array_merge($withDistance, $withoutDistance);
```

Comment: you did understand my comment right. I only slightly adjusted your code

Comment: This one is faster. `if ( $a['distance'] == $b['distance']) return 0;` didn't sort the array correctly (if two had the same distance, they weren't sorted based on their former position) `return 1` fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Filter items with NULL in distance
$withoutDistance = array_filter($array, function($item) { return !$item["distance"];});
// Take the rest 
$withDistance = array_diff_assoc($array, $withoutDistance);
// Sort by distance
usort($withDistance, function($a, $b){ 
      if ( $a['distance'] == $b['distance']) return 0;;
      return $a['distance'] > $b['distance'] ? 1: -1; });
// Return NULL distance into array
$array = array_merge($withDistance, $withoutDistance);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's sorting functions are not ['stable'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). So you cannot predict in which order the result will be if the compare function returns 0. You'll have to write your own function, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353739/preserve-key-order-stable-sort-when-sorting-with-phps-uasort).

Comment: Thanks for the stable hint

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353739/preserve-key-order-stable-sort-when-sorting-with-phps-uasort#comment134189207_4353739

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do exactly what you want, but keep in mind the array_reverse!.

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){

    $isBFalse = is_bool($b['distance']) && $b['distance'] == false;
    $isAFalse = is_bool($a['distance']) && $a['distance'] == false;

    if($isBFalse && $isAFalse){
        return 0;
    }else if($isBFalse){
        return 1;
    }
    else if($isAFalse){
        return -1;
    }

    return $a['distance'] - $b['distance'];
});

$array = array_reverse($array);
```

Comment: The values with a distance are sorted DESC, but should be ASC. You can get the same result if you only use return `$a['distance'] - $b['distance'];`

Answer (score 0):

A solution that sorts the array in two steps. The first step computes for each element a sort key and stores it in the element itself. The second step does the actual sort using a simple string comparison of the sort keys created on the first step.

The code:

```
$new = array_map(
    function (array $item) {
        return array(
            'name'     => $item['name'],
            'distance' => $item['distance'],
            'sort_key' => sprintf('%020.6f/%s',
                    $item['distance'] === false ? 999999 : $item['distance'],
                    $item['name']),
        );
    },
    $array
);

usort(
    $new,
    function (array $a, array $b) {
        return strcmp($a['sort_key'], $b['sort_key']);
    }
);
```

The sorted array is in variable `$new`, the original array `$array` is not affected.

#### How it works

The first step generates a new array. Each entry in the array contains the original entry from `$array` plus an extra property named `sort_key`.

The value of `sort_key` is a string that is used for sorting. The sorting criteria are:

- compare the value of `distance` and put `false` at the end; that means `false` is bigger than any non-`false` value;
- on tie, use the value of `name`;

In order to sort `false` as greater than any non-`false` `distance`, replace `false` with a big number. The code above uses `999999`. Adjust this value to be sure it is bigger than any `distance`.

Because the strings are sorted using the dictionary order, the value of `distance` (with `false` replaced with `999999`) is formatted as a fixed-length string (20 characters, 6 of them are decimals), left-padded with `0`.

The name is appended to this string; it is already string and it does not need any other processing.

```
sprintf('%020.6f/%s',
           $item['distance'] === false ? 999999 : $item['distance'],
           $item['name']),
);
```

For `Array 1`, the [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) above generates:

```
0000000000003.400000/Array 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort with the spaceship operator and two rules:

1. sort ascending if `distance` is `false`, then
2. sort by `distance`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dGMNj))

```
usort(
    $array,
    fn($a, $b) => [$a['distance'] === false, $a['distance']]
                  <=>
                  [$b['distance'] === false, $b['distance']]
);
var_export($array);
```